# Execute immediate dbms_output.put_line

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have code like this:

```
set serveroutput on

declare
v_str varchar2(200);
begin
v_str := q'!dbms_output.put_line('Hello world');!';
Execute immediate v_str;
end;
```

Oracle SQL Developer says that there's invalid SQL Statement, what's the problem?

Comment: Use `show err` to print detail on the error.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to call dbms_output with dynamic PL/SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
declare
v_str varchar2(200);
begin
v_str := q'!begin dbms_output.put_line('Hello world'); end;!';
Execute immediate v_str;
end;
/
```

works...

Comment: Basically, the answer is that `dbms_output` is a procedure and so can only be executed within a PL/SQL block.

Comment: @Ben - really a reply to a comment on your deleted answer, but still relevant here; the `q` syntax is in the documentation under [text literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/sql_elements003.htm#i42617).